# .NET how to programatically detect and decode text in a received SMTP email encoded as base64 or other?

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, encoding, smtp

How can I programmatically detect and decode an encoded text in a received SMTP email?

Users communicate with my artificially intelligent online system by sending it an email that contains a text message from user.

If no encoding, then my AI successfully parses messages from user.

But some email services may encode the text.  How can I determine and decode encoded text?  For example, MS Outlook will encode email English text as base64, and my system them gets an email like this:

```
<and the boiler plating just before the base64 encoding...>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-OriginatorOrg: hotmail.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-originalarrivaltime: 14 Jul 2017 13:23:27.5314
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-fromentityheader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: CO1NAM04HT166
Return-Path: douglaskbell@hotmail.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 14 Jul 2017 13:23:30.0507 (UTC) FILETIME=[6287D1B0:01D2FCA4]
FGFYUEHEGVWSCSDFXYHLDULIENGLIFUWVCKSJBDUFWKUEB..  <<<<<<<<<< base64 encoding
```

Comment: It's written right there on the 2nd line. "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` header is the key, but you may be better of using a MIME parser, e.g. [MimeKit](http://www.mimekit.net/), which should be able to handle either format.

```
Dim smtp = "raw SMTP message"
Using ms = New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(smtp))
    Dim opt = New ParserOptions()
    Dim msg = MimeMessage.Load(opt, ms, False)
    Console.WriteLine(msg.TextBody)
End Using
```

Note that I don't know much about SMTP, so I'm not sure that using UTF8 for the entire message is correct (the headers should be ASCII, but not sure about the body).  The `Load` method also has versions that take a stream, so depending on how you are getting your messages, that may work better.